# RxJava. Observable.delay work strange (lacks some items at the end)

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm trying to understand RxJava. My test code is:

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.functions.Action1;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Observable<String> observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    subscriber.onNext("a");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    subscriber.onNext("b");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    subscriber.onNext("c");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    subscriber.onNext("d");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    subscriber.onNext("e");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    subscriber.onNext("f");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    subscriber.onNext("g");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    subscriber.onNext("h");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
            }
        });

        observable
                .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(String string) {
                        System.out.println(string);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Without `.delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` i have the output: a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
but with `.delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`
the output lacks "g" and "h":
a
b
c
d
e
f

How can that be? Documentation says that delay just emits the items emitted by the source Observable shifted forward in time by a specified delay

Comment: Your main thread quits before it can observe the final value. You can either sleep long enough or use toBlocking to await all values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `delay` overload that you are using schedules work on a different thread and results in an implicit race condition.All temporal operators (such as `delay`, `buffer`, and `window`) need to use a scheduler to schedule the effect for later and this can result in unexpected race conditions if you aren't aware of it and use them carefully. In this case the delay operator schedules the work downstream on a separate thread pool. Here is the order of execution (on the main thread) in your test.

1. Your Observable is subscribed to and waits 1000 millis before `onNext("a")`
2. Next it's received by the delay. This schedules the downstream onNext for 2 seconds later.
3. Control flow returns immediately to your observable which waits 1000 millis.
4. Observable `onNext("b")` to delay. Delay schedules the onNext of "b" for 2 seconds later.
5. .... (repeat)
6. When your observable calls `onNext("h")` it schedules the work then immediately returns from subscribe and terminates your test (causing the scheduled work to disappear).

In order to get it to execute asynchronously you you can schedule the delay on the trampoline scheduler implementation.

```
.delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.trampoline())
```

Comment: to make it async use ```Schedulers.io```

Comment: Worked perfectly !!

Comment: Note that the `Schedulers.io` uses an unbounded thread pool. Use `Schedulers.computation` for a bounded thread pool. Computation is typically used for CPU intensive work, while IO is for potentially blocking work.